# Getting Github oauth callback url 'code' query param in next auth 5

Tags: next.js, next-auth, github-oauth

I'm using next.js 14.1.0 and next-auth 5.0.0-beta.11.  I have oauth login via github working.  During the login process, github sends me a code as a query param to the callback url that I specified when I set up the github oauth app.  I want to get this code so I can send to my django rest framework api to do some things with it.

In the network tab of the console I can see what I want to get:

http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/github?code=6c2b8421e341ed8caa2f

But I haven't been able to figure out how to grab this.

In my next auth set up, there is a dynamic route (api/auth/[...nextauth]) with a route.ts file containing export { GET, POST } from '@/auth';  The callback url would redirect the user logging in to here.... I don't know how to do this.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

I tried importing useSearchParams in my login component, which is a client component.  But that doesn't work, i just get an undefined variable.

Comment: You are doing an Authorization Code Flow, where the spec of OAuth wants that the server that handle the callback URL (localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/…), in your case Next.js, to grab the code and exchange it with an access token. Why would you want to send it to another backend?

Comment: I want to get this code so I can send to my django rest framework api to do some things with it.

Luckily I figured out how to grab the code using my middleware.  I put the callback url in my matcher, and used nextUrl.searchParams.get('code')..

Posting questions here is not very helpful.